# JS change image if/else

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to change image when function ends. In IF image should change, and in else, image stays the same.

html

```
    <img class="owner" id="regina" src="img/uk-profile.jpg" alt="Great Britain">
  <p class="fort"><b>Fort: </b><span  id="wall">1000</span></p>
```

What i have tried in JS

```
function finish(){
    var f = document.getElementById('wall');

    if (f>-1) {
        alert("Battle has been won, you now control the region!");
        var g = document.getElementById('regina').src = "img/us-profile";

    }


     else {
        alert("Battle has been lost!");


     }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Start with getting the text  content of span i.e.  `var f  = parseInt(document.getElementById('wall').textContent.trim(), 10)`;

Comment: feeling embarrassed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
var f = document.getElementById('wall');
```

In f you have the element not the value of the element, do the following: use `.innerHTML` to get the value and convert it to int, then you can check `if (f > -1)`

```
var f = parseInt(document.getElementById('wall').innerHTML);
```

```js
function finish() {
  var f = parseInt(document.getElementById('wall').innerHTML);
  if (f > -1) {
    alert("Battle has been won, you now control the region!");
    var g = document.getElementById('regina').src = "http://www.newseum.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/xwinner.jpg.pagespeed.ic.iQ7m1XtFLg.jpg";

  } else {
    alert("Battle has been lost!");


  }
}

finish();
```

```html
<img class="owner" id="regina" src="img/uk-profile.jpg" alt="Great Britain">
<p class="fort"><b>Fort: </b><span id="wall">1000</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if `wall` is more than `-1`, in your case is `1000`, than you need to take value from that element and convert it to a number 
Like this:

```
function finish(){
    var f = document.getElementById('wall').innerHTML;
    f = parseInt(f)

    if (f>-1) {
        alert("Battle has been won, you now control the region!");
        var g = document.getElementById('regina').src = "img/us-profile.src";
    }

     else {
        alert("Battle has been lost!");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to check if the text inside "wall" is bigger than -1? if so, this is the way you should check the innerHTML like this:

```
if (f.innerHTML > -1)
```

if you are trying to check if wall exist, just check if f returns true:

```
if(f)
```

the changing of the src works, it just always go to the else. changing the code to one of the above should help.